# Usages of doThrow() doAnswer() doNothing() and doReturn() in mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I was learning mockito and I understood the basic usages of the above mentioned functions from the [link](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12).

But I would like to know whether it can be used for any other cases?

Comment: Sadly, *the link* is down.

Answer (score 148):

**doThrow** : Basically used when you want to throw an exception when a method is being called within a mock object.

```
public void validateEntity(final Object object){}
Mockito.doThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class)
.when(validationService).validateEntity(Matchers.any(AnyObjectClass.class));
```

**doReturn** :  Used when you want to send back a return value when a method is executed.

```
public Socket getCosmosSocket() throws IOException {}
Mockito.doReturn(cosmosSocket).when(cosmosServiceImpl).getCosmosSocket();
```

**doAnswer**: Sometimes you need to do some actions with the arguments that are passed to the method, for example, add some values, make some calculations or even modify them doAnswer gives you the Answer<?> interface that being executed in the moment that method is called, this interface allows you to interact with the parameters via the InvocationOnMock argument. Also, the return value of answer method will be the return value of the mocked method.

```
public ReturnValueObject quickChange(Object1 object);
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<ReturnValueObject>() {

        @Override
        public ReturnValueObject answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

            final Object1 originalArgument = (invocation.getArguments())[0];
            final ReturnValueObject returnedValue = new ReturnValueObject();
            returnedValue.setCost(new Cost());

            return returnedValue ;
        }
}).when(priceChangeRequestService).quickCharge(Matchers.any(Object1.class));
```

**doNothing**: (From [documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.12.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing--))
Use doNothing() for setting void methods to do nothing. Beware that void methods on mocks do nothing by default! However, there are rare situations when doNothing() comes handy:

- Stubbing consecutive calls on a void method:

  ```
  doNothing().
  doThrow(new RuntimeException())
  .when(mock).someVoidMethod();

  //does nothing the first time:
  mock.someVoidMethod();

  //throws RuntimeException the next time:
  mock.someVoidMethod();
  ```
- When you spy real objects and you want the void method to do nothing:

  ```
  List list = new LinkedList();
  List spy = spy(list);

  //let's make clear() do nothing
  doNothing().when(spy).clear();

  spy.add("one");

  //clear() does nothing, so the list still contains "one"
  spy.clear();
  ```

Comment: Is not doNothing() same as if we actually never write this stub in first place ?
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to Karan's question. My understanding is it's *not* the same thing because if you don't write the stub, then you're not instructing that particular method to avoid conducting it's regular behavior, which may result in it interfering with your unit test, and since you're not stubbing out the dependency, it's actually an integration test. If you *do* use the `doNothing()` method then you're effectively telling the method (whether void or whatever) to do nothing, as opposed to it's regular, potentially conflicting behavior. I'm a newb so correct me if needed.

Comment: @nova you are right,  if we have a dependency and we call a method that returns nothing (void) if you don't use doNothing you will call the real method, which is outside of the class that you are testing. This link will be helpful http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing()

Comment: Yes, just to add to that: you'll find the compiler won't actually let you do `doReturn` on a `void` method, and won't let you do `doNothing()` on a value-returning method: there's nothing magical about `doNothing()`, in other words: its the exact counterpart to `doReturn`, for a `void` method: in both cases you're telling it not to do its normal stuff...

Answer (score 8):

To add a bit to accepted answer ...

If you get an `UnfinishedStubbingException`, be sure to set the method to be stubbed **after** the `when` closure, which is different than when you write `Mockito.when`

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(mock).method()    //method is declared after 'when' closes

Mockito.when(mock.method()).thenReturn(something)   //method is declared inside 'when'
```

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the kind of test double you want to interact with:

- If you don't use doNothing and you **mock** an object, the real method is not called
- If you don't use doNothing and you **spy** an object, the real method is called

In other words, with mocking the only useful interactions with a collaborator are the ones that you provide. By default functions will return null, void methods do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple example is that if you have a `UserService` that has `@Autowired` jpa resposiroty `UserRepository`

```
...
class UserService{

  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;
...
}
```

then in the test class for `UserService` you will do

```
...
class TestUserService{
  @Mock 
  UserRepository userRepository;

  @InjectMocks
  UserService userService;

...
}
```

`@InjectMocks` tells the framework that take the `@Mock UserRepository userRespository;` and inject that into `userService` so rather than auto wiring a real instance of `UserRepository` a Mock of `UserRepository` will be injected in `userService`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing a logic class and it is calling some internal void methods the doNothing is perfect.