# Mockito throws exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
public interface ABC {
        public boolean removeUser(String userId) throws OTPServiceException, RemoteException;
}

ABC abc= mock(ABC.class);
doNothing().when(abc).removeUser(anyString());
```

I have tried like this. I got below exception.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Only void methods can doNothing()!
Example of correct use of doNothing():
    doNothing().
    doThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Above means:
someVoidMethod() does nothing the 1st time but throws an exception the 2nd time is called
```

Comment: And what worries you?

Comment: can you please explain what is your question

Comment: He is asking you what your question is. The message is very clear "Only void methods can doNothing()!" So you google that message and fix your problem?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't `doNothing` for non-`void` methods because you need either return something or throw exception.

```
when(abc.removeUser(anyString())).thenReturn(true);

when(abc.removeUser(anyString())).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);
```

Answer (score 7):

You method returns a boolean, so you should mock a boolean response.

You should have something like this:

```
when(abc.removeUser(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
```

You can check [Usages of doThrow() doAnswer() doNothing() and doReturn() in mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836778/usages-of-dothrow-doanswer-donothing-and-doreturn-in-mockito) for a more detailed and simple explaination.

Comment: Edited the response to make it right.

I was calling thenReturn on removeUser(anyString()) and it should be called on the result of the when(...) method.