# Mockito void doAnswer correct usage & purpose

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Today I learned about Mockito and while playing around with it I found something I do not understand.

Say I would like to test the following piece of code:

```
    public void stop(boolean showMessage) {
    if(executor != null && !executor.isShutdown() && this.isRunning) {
        if(showMessage) { 
            View.getSingleton().showMessageDialog(Constant.messages.getString("sessionchecker.stopmessage"));
        }

        executor.shutdownNow();
        executor = null;
        extension.getCountdownTimer().stopCountdown();

        this.isRunning = false;
        this.usersReady.clear();
    }
}
```

Since the stop method is a void I would need to call `doAnswer` (If I understand correctly).
So I tried the following:

```
    @Test
public void testStopIsRunningFalse() {
    Mockito.when(controller.isRunning()).thenReturn(true); // Mock a running service
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            if(controller.isRunning()) {
                // Normally would actually shut down service
                Mockito.when(controller.isRunning()).thenReturn(false); // Service should stop
            }
            return null;
        }
    }).when(controller).stop(false);
    controller.stop(false);
    boolean expected = false;
    assertEquals(expected, controller.isRunning());
}
```

I, however, do not understand what the purpose of a test like this would be. Why would I test it like this since this will never fail (the parameter `isRunning` is being set as I would expect it to be). 
Basically I only need to test the state of certain fields (`isRunning` and `executor` for example). These fields do not have public getters or setters however..

Therefore, I think I misunderstand the usage of the `deAnswer`. Could someone help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836778/usages-of-dothrow-doanswer-donothing-and-doreturn-in-mockito

Comment: I have read that question, and I'm looking for a more specific answer (Call me stupid but I'm having trouble reflecting the given answer there to my situation).

Comment: did you look mockito documentation.

Comment: @want2learn Yes I have, the problem is that the example and explanation there is even more generic than the answer above.

Comment: https://testing.googleblog.com/2014/03/whenhow-to-use-mockito-answer.html ?

Comment: @RC. Thanks for this suggestion. I have found that I have been getting at this a little bit wrong (I think). I do not necessarily need to stub the objects. The problem is i need to test fields (like isrunning and executor) without public getter.

Comment: `ReflectionTestUtils.getField` (from spring-test) or some manual reflection should be possible

Comment: This is a bad idea. We don't test code, we test behaviour. You're not supposed to create tests in terms of implementation, you're meant to create a rig within which you can try out the implementation to see what effect it has on the outside world.

If you think the state of the fields matters to the outside world, then make them accessible. If not, then test what happens when you run your code.

Comment: @Ashley Frieze (Sorry, not native English) If I understand correctly, you're saying that the stop method (for example) should not be tested with Unit tests because my fields are not accessible, and in order to test them they should be therefor do not test them?

Comment: @RC If using Mockito, just use `@InjectMocks`, which works perfectly well for private non-settable fields.

Comment: I think @Asley Frieze was suggesting something a little more abstract, i.e., that the best tests are going to treat your methods like "black-boxes". So rather than looking at the code and trying to figure out how to test the code, figure out how to test the behavior that you are trying to create with the code.

Comment: @KevinWelker what I did understand is that the OP wants to read some private field, so..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your code example, it appears you are mocking the object you want to test, which is a no-no 99.9% of the time.  You generally only want to mock direct collaborators of the class you are testing.  Collaborators consist of things such as injected services (or other injected fields), and arguments of the method you are testing -- essentially anything that represents initial state of your class under test before you invoke the method being tested.

Comment: I am indeed mocking the whole class, and now that I think of what you're saying, that sounds logical. The fields in the stop method (like executor) are not accessible nor settable outside the stop and the start method. Considering this and what you are suggesting, that would mean the methodes cannot be unit tested?

Comment: I don't have your full code, but I assume you mean that fields like executor are private without setters.  So to mock this collaborator and get it into the test you can use the `@InjectMocks` Mockito annotation on your field for the class under test, and then declare and annotate with `@Mock` an Executor field in your test class.  That will allow even private fields to be injected into your class being tested, using Mockito "magic".  This gets done either by applying a Mockito JUnit runner to your test, or by invoking `Mockito.initMocks()` static method in the JUnit `@Before` (setup) method.

Comment: Accepted together with comments from original question. Thanks guys!

Comment: you made my day @KevinWelker, simple and precise